# Display Array Data in Select Box - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, select

I am a newbie to Ruby and I am facing an issue.

I am trying to display an array data in select box but somehow it shows empty box.

Here is my controller :-

```
def update_center
    @center = ["center1", "center2"]
    render :update do |page|
      page.replace_html "center_list", :partial => "center_list"
    end
  end
```

Here is my view code :-

```
<%= select :abc, :center, @center,
            {:prompt => "Select Center"},
            {:onChange => "#{remote_function(:url => {:action => "update_b"}}"} %>
```

It renders correctly but in the select box it just prompts Select Center.
Kindly please let me know where am I going wrong. Code is in ruby 1.8.7

Thank you

Comment: Try using select tag instead of select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried, everything seems to be correct, except your syntax above should be

```
<%= select :abc, :center, @center,
            {:prompt => "Select Center"},
            {:onChange => "#{remote_function(:url => {:action => "update_b"})}"} %>
```